# sql syntax without top

Tags: asp.net, sql, syntax

im using this query atm by i want to order by TagReplies. But when It wont allow me to save it unless i specify top or for after second select but i want all results.

```
AS
 SELECT
Tag,
TagReplies, 
(TagReplies*1.00) AS Weight,
TagTopics, 
(TagTopics*1.00) AS Weight2

FROM
(
SELECT
    Tags.Tag
    ,SUM(T.TopicReplies) As TagReplies
    ,Count(T.TopicId) As TagTopics
FROM
       Tags
    INNER JOIN Topics T ON Tags.TopicId = T.TopicId
GROUP BY
    Tags.Tag
if add this eg ORDER BY TagReplies DESC
)  T
```

it works fine if i add a top

Comment: Why do you need an `ORDER BY` in the derived table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message you're getting.  You can't use `ORDER BY` in a subquery.  You can only `ORDER BY` for the whole query.  `ORDER BY` works with `TOP` as a special case in subqueries because that determines what records constitute the `TOP`.

Try this:

```
SELECT
Tag,
TagReplies, 
(TagReplies*1.00) AS Weight,
TagTopics, 
(TagTopics*1.00) AS Weight2

FROM
(
SELECT
    Tags.Tag
    ,SUM(T.TopicReplies) As TagReplies
    ,Count(T.TopicId) As TagTopics
FROM
       Tags
    INNER JOIN Topics T ON Tags.TopicId = T.TopicId
GROUP BY
    Tags.Tag
)  T
ORDER BY TagReplies DESC
```

Additionally, it looks like this might be part of a `VIEW` definition.  You can't specify an `ORDER BY` clause in a `VIEW` definition.  You must do it when you `SELECT` from the `VIEW`.